# In Pandas, how to concatenate horizontally with interleaving the columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two .csv files A and B which look like

A : Col1, Col2, Col3

B: Col1, Col2, Col3

The column names are identical in both the .csv files. How to I concatenate them horizontally so that
the resultant file C looks like

C: Col1 (from A), Col1 (from B), Col2 (from A), Col2 (from B)....

Can think of pd.concat([A,B], axis=1) but that will place columns of one file after another. I want them interleaved in the way I have shown above.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe you can use loop to iterate over each column, something like the below:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_csv('fileA.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('fileB.csv')

# Create an empty dataframe to hold the result
data_interleaved = pd.DataFrame()

# Interleave the columns
for column in data1.columns:
    data_interleaved[f'{column}_from_A'] = data1[column]
    data_interleaved[f'{column}_from_B'] = data2[column]

df_interleaved.to_csv('fileC.csv', index=False)
```

This method need both files to have the same number of rows, otherwise there may be issues. If they do not have the same number of rows but you still want to merge them, you will need to decide on a strategy to handle the discrepancy (for example, filling missing values with NaN or with some specific value).

Comment: Thanks for the response. They may have different number of rows. If I want to fill missing value with NaN, what changes should I make to your script?